# check if an HtmlElement has a directive

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I would like to know how to check if an Element implements some directive.
I have two directives, a Sortable and a SortableItem, once the onDrop within SortableItem fires, I will call some binded function on the Sortable parent.
The problem is that the target of the drop event is some element within the SortableItem element, thus, I need to find the original SortableItem that is being used as dropzone.
I am doing it by looping through the parents of the event.target and checking if the Element has the attribute selector of the SortableItem, however, I have the feeling that this is no the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the type of the directives you can use `@ViewChild()`, `@ViewChildren()`, `@ContentChild()`, or `@contentChildren()` to query for elements with that directive

```
@ViewChildren(Sortable) QueryList<Sortable> sortables;
@ViewChildren(SortableItem) QueryList<SortableItem> sortableItems;
```

When the directives contain

```
class Sortable {
  final ElementRef elementRef;
  Sortable(this.elementRef);
```

you can search the `QueryList` to find the matching element.

```
someEvent(Element sortable) {
  var found = sortables.toArray().firstWhere((s) => s.elementRef == sortable, orElse: () => null);
  print(found);
}
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components contains a sortable list. It might provide some hints how to do this in Angular2.

Comment: I would like to use angular2_components, but I find it kinda bugged. Don't take me wrong, but I have no idea it says that google uses angular 3 alpha. I tried it and it seemed its far away from production, unfortunatelly